# How to prove this series converges (possibly by modifying the Dirichlet test)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove convergence of the series
$(1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}+\sin(n)}$.

If this series were $(2) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$, then it converges by the Dirichlet test because partial sums of $\sin(n)$ are bounded and $1/\sqrt{n}$ decreases monotonically to $0$.

The difficulty I have is that $\sqrt{n}+ \sin(n)$ in the denominator is not monotonic and $\sin(n)$ in the numerator changes sign. But the denominator is bracketed by monotonic sequences $\sqrt{n} - 1 \leq \sqrt{n} + \sin(n) \leq \sqrt{n} + 1$ and it seems possible to adapt the Dirichlet test.

Can this be done to prove convergence of (1) or is there a more general approach that I am not aware of?

Comment: Vuk's answer demonstrates a very general technique: faced with things like that, you can do a Taylor series development of the summand to get several series, until a point where the reminder gives an absolutely convergent series. Then, you have a sum of several series, the last one being absolutely convergent: analyze the others as you want, e.g., Dirichlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me help you with this one.

We can rewrite the following expression as follows: 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin(n)}\cdot(\sin(n)+n^{1/2})^{-1} \tag{1}
$$ then we can take $n^{1/2}$ out and write it like 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{\sin(n)}{n^{1/2}}}\cdot\left (1+\frac{\sin(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}
$$ 
now we can apply the taylor series like
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{\sin(n)}{n^{1/2}}}\cdot\left(1-\frac{\sin(n)}{n^{1/2}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\tag{3}$$

from here you can solve it, first one converges by Dirichlet, second one diverges, third one converges.

Comment: Nice. $+1$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: (I took the liberty to improve the formatting and add the $O(1/n)$ term. I hope that's OK.)

Comment: Yap, its fine, i am not so skilled in writing, thank you for doing it!

Answer (score 0):

$a(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}+\sin(n)},
b(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
b(m)-a(m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (\dfrac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}}-\dfrac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}+\sin(n)})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \sin(n)(\dfrac{\sin(n)}{(\sqrt{n}+\sin(n))(\sqrt{n})})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)}\\
\end{array}
$

This last sum
looks like it diverges.
Numerical experimentation
suggests it grows like
$\ln(m)/2+.3
\approx(\ln(m)+\gamma)/2
$.

Since
$b(m)$ converges
(to about 1, it seems),
this would imply that
$a(m)$ diverges
like about
$-\ln(m)/2$.

Comment: The last sum has positive terms, and (for  large enough $n$l we have $\frac{\sin^2 n}{n+\sqrt n \ sin n} > \frac{\sin^2 n}{2n}$. That's enough to conclude...